# getDeclaredFields() absolute performance

Tags: java, performance

I have a Java class that represents an entry in a database. So each field is a column in the database.

When I want to update that database, I construct a ContentValues object.

Is

```
ArrayList<T> contentValues = new ArrayList<T>()

//bla bla add ten items to contentValues`
```

faster than

```
ArrayList<T> = new ArrayList<T>(ThisClass.class.getDeclaredFields().length);
//bla bla add ten items to contentValues
```

What is the absolute performance of `getDeclaredFields`?  I hope someone could actually point out how `getDeclaredFields` works. I know how a resize of a container works but I don't know anything about how `getDeclaredFields` works and how that would perform.

Comment: Is initializing with no capacity, so the contentValues will potentially have to resize, faster than specifying the capacity using the reflection method getDeclaredFields.

Comment: @DimaGoltsman The question is there. He specifically asked if the one method is faster than the other. Did you read the question or are you just here to complain?

Comment: Are you asking about the absolute performance of `getDeclaredFields()`, as per your title, or about creating `ArrayList` with and without an initial capacity, as per your text?

Comment: My question is about the absolute performance of getDeclaredFields. The example in my text is for relevance, is the performance of getDeclaredFields static and fast enough to be worth specifying for the size of containers or would it be more harm than good on average or perhaps just a corner case...

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that. Is there some reason why you can't test and measure for yourself, thus obtaining a *fact* rather than an unbounded set of opinions?

Comment: Benchmark is acceptable although I was really hoping someone could actually point out how getDeclaredFields works. I know how a resize of a container works but I don't know anything about how getDeclaredFields works and how that would perform. I was certainly not asking for anybodies opinion... Which part of my question seemed to be seeking opinion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Micro benchmark with a simple HashMap using the same settings as [ContentValues](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/content/ContentValues.java#ContentValues) (assuming this is the class you are referring to), and adding 10 fields (i.e. one resizing operation):

```
Benchmark                                    Mean   Mean error          Var    Units
c.a.p.g.a.Reflection.getDeclaredFields     326.405        5.989       33.961  nsec/op
c.a.p.g.a.Reflection.resize                247.581        7.377       51.520  nsec/op
```

So `getDeclaredFields` is somewhat slower than resizing the map once, but the difference is only of the order of 100 nanoseconds on a desktop PC.

When adding more fields to `ThisClass`, `getDeclaredFields` gets slower, so I would favour the auto-resizing approach.

Code:

```
@GenerateMicroBenchmark(BenchmarkType.AverageTimePerOp)
public Map getDeclaredFields() {
    Map m = new HashMap(ThisClass.class.getDeclaredFields().length, 1.0f);
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        m.put(i, "a");
    }
    return m;
}

@GenerateMicroBenchmark(BenchmarkType.AverageTimePerOp)
public Map resize() {
    Map m = new HashMap(8, 0.75f);
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        m.put(i, "a");
    }
    return m;
}

class ThisClass {
    private int i, j, k;
    public String s, t, u;
    protected List l, m, n;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! cool benchmark there, I'll have to look into doing that myself in future. Is that standard java?

Comment: @Pork Added a comment: with more fields, `getDeclaredFields` gets slower so auto-resize seems to always be better (unless you can store the result of `getDeclaredFields.length` and reuse it of course).

Comment: I'm using [the openJDK jmh library](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) for benchmarking.

Comment: Thanks for that addition Assylias, useful to know, so I guess it's doing dynamic work, which is what I feared might be the case. Thanks again!

Comment: OP will clearly need to iterate over those declared fields, so he won't be avoiding that call in any case. It's just about writing the code so that only one call is made. (BTW +1 for jmh, I guess I'll switch to it from Caliper now!).

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Yes if he needs the call anyway then it's better to use it - I should have added that sizing the map initially with a constant (10 in my example), is about twice as fast, so worth doing if you have the value at hand. I've been using jmh and once you get used to it it is quite simple and easy to use (and it runs on Windows).

Comment: Well I will be going through the fields by name anyway, but just wanted to avoid magic numbers if I was initialising the container and be defensive IF getDeclaredField() actually had a constant performance profile.

Answer (score -2):

```
ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues()
```

I would say the execution time difference is not sigificant.

Comment: I would say that it isn't significant either.

But I'm asking for anyone that knows the implementation and performance of getDeclaredFields that is the performance predictable and efficient to use when declaring the size of containers, similar to if you were specifying the size of a copied array, you wouldn't hesitate about using the length of the array to initialize the size of the new array.